# Is Cognito overkill for simply authenticating a user with Google+ account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I am creating a simple application that I want to keep user data on the backend (like an email, where an admin can add emails for user accounts) if they are in the db, then I want them to log in using their google+ account. I originally looked into google-oauth in coordination with passport and mongoose, which I implemented well, but my boss is having me use dynamodb. So I have ditched mongodb from the project. Whenever I research dynamodb with auth it comes up with Cognito. I get it, they want to sell more services. However, this is overkill for my project, I don't need to tie in authentication with multiple devices yet. I simply want to save a user's info in dynamodb - look up that information when logging in, if there, authenticate with google oauth and move on. But I am having a hard time finding resources to do this in a simple way with aws and dynamodb. Any help is appreciated. Any tutorials are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWS cogntio comes in role when you want to provide added security to let users access your AWS resources, it provides access rights with limited privileges. You can give as much access rights as you want for the resources like DynamoDB tables etc.
But as in your case you don't need AWS cognito.
So try finding out AWS DynamoDB implementation, you will need to provide the access key for that.
So you should create an IAM role where you will define the DynamoDB table that you want your users to access.
So look for DynamoDB implementation and IAM role.